# AttributeError: module 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'CarRacing' / box 2d doesn't install successfully

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

```
environment_name = 'CarRacing-v0'
env = gym.make(environment_name)
```

**AttributeError: module 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'CarRacing'**

and i did pip install box2d in anaconda prompt
but it gives me some error and i cannot install box2d

> error: command 'C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\gcc.exe' failed with exit code 1  ----------------------------------------
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for box2d

and also i did other tries in anaconda prompt

```
conda create -c conda-forge -n gymenv swig pip 
conda activate gymenv
pip install Box2D gym
```

but still this error comes out

> AttributeError: module 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'CarRacing'

how can i solve this error...?
and i also added swig in environment variables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd9I9.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the `pyglet` package is not installed,
so it cannot run.

try to do:
`pip install pyglet`